# How to transfer android's properties to my compound view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to create a Compound view which consists of an ImageView a TextView and an EditText

I found [this lovely tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#tutorial_compoundcontrols) on how to do that, and my compound view looks great

Now I want to copy all the properties a TextView has , all the properties the EditText has and all the properties the ImageView

so that i can style them via xml inside my custom view.

```
 <declare-styleable name="MyCustomView">
        <attr name="mcv_label" format="string" />
        <attr name="mcv_fieldText" format="string" />
        <attr name="mcv_fieldHint" format="string" />
        <attr name="mcv_label_id" format="reference" />
        <attr name="mcv_field_id" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

And am of course able to define them in xml

the point is I want to do

```
 <com.lenabru.myapp.widget.MyCustomView
        style="@style/tableRowStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        mcv:mcv_label_id="@+id/tvLabel"
        android:text="@string/someText" <=== this line 
          />
```

without aliasing all the properties into mcv stylable
is it possible to do ?

MyCustomView.java

```
public class MyCustomView extends TableRow{

private EditText editText;
private TextView label;
    private ImageView image;
private int labelId;
private int formFieldId;

public FormField(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    initAttributes(context,attrs, 0);
}

public FormField(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initAttributes(context,null, 0);
}


private void initAttributes(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_field, this,true);
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
    editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FormField, defStyle, 0);

    if(a.hasValue(R.styleable.MyCustomView_mvc_label_id)) {
        labelId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.FormField_ff_label_id, 0);
        if(labelId!=0) {
            label.setId(labelId);
        }
    }


    a.recycle();
}
```

}

Comment: This is not an answer, just a **suggestion**: `a Compound view which consists of an ImageView a TextView and an EditText`. Do you know that **you can get rid of the ImageView**, by using a TextView's **compound drawables**? Flattening your design is a **performance improvement**.

Comment: Ok but that still doesnt solve my problem of putting an inputType in XML, which would mean i'd have to relist all the enum values android provides for my view to be correct

Comment: Well, my one was just an optimization tip, no answer.

Comment: @LenaBru actually what is your goal?

Comment: @pskink i want to create a view that has a combination of other android views, and i want them to be styleable in xml, but i don't want to copy all the properties from android's views into my styleable declarations, there are too many, is there are a way to just project them some way?

Comment: @LenaBru you don't need to copy anything,  you can just use them a. g.  android:background="#f00"

Comment: my view extends TableRow which in turn extends LinearLayout. attributes like "input type" are not available...

Comment: but you still can use it and get via context.obtainStyledAttributes